# Why won't my code run for a "Guess My Number" game?

Tags: java

I tried to put together a simple guess my number game. You input a number, the computer outputs a random number, and tells you how far off you were. There aren't any errors in the code according to intellij, but it won't run. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ThinkJava {

    //guess my number
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //random number generator
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int guess = in.nextInt();
        int difference = guess - number;

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number 1-100 (including both). Can you guess what it is?");
        in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your guess is: " + guess);
        System.out.println("The number I was thinking of was: " + number);
        System.out.println("You were off by: " + difference);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your line `int guess = in.nextInt();` is going to stop for input before printing anything, then you have another `in.nextInt();` after your prompt (which you don't store anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run without any problem (it does for me), but not with the expected behaviour. Your game prompts for the number guess before any message is displayed:

```
int guess = in.nextInt();
```

Then, you have another prompt after the first message which requires another user input to continue:

```
System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number 1-100 (including both). Can you guess what it is?");
in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Your guess is: " + guess);
```

When you enter a second number at this point the program will display the last messages, but without taking into account the last input (as it was not assigned to a variable), and the guess and the difference info will reference the first number entered, making it confusing.

You should get rid of the second prompt and replace it with the first one, moving it (as well as the subsequent line which calculates the difference, as this depends on the first one).

Also, you should `close()` the Scanner when you are not using it anymore, to release the resource.

So, finally:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number 1-100 (including both). Can you guess what it is?");

int guess = in.nextInt();
int difference = guess - number;

System.out.println("Your guess is: " + guess);
System.out.println("The number I was thinking of was: " + number);
System.out.println("You were off by: " + difference);

in.close();
```